# Declaring and using variables in PL-SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL-SQL.  I do not understand why I am getting the error "PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement"

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create a variable c_limit and load it's value.  I then want to use that variable later to filter data.

Basically I am playing around in the demo db to see what I can/can't do with PL-SQL.

The code worked up to the point that I added "select * from demo_orders where CUSTOMER_ID = custID;"

```
declare 
c_limit NUMBER(9,2);
custID INT;

BEGIN
  custID := 6;

  -- Save the credit limit
  select credit_limit INTO c_limit
  from  demo_customers cust
  where customer_id = custID;

  select * from demo_orders where CUSTOMER_ID = custID;

  dbms_output.Put_line(c_limit);
END;
```

Comment: You have to `select * from demo_orders where CUSTOMER_ID = custID;` into something, as you did it in the first query.  It looks like you don't need this query anyway, so just comment or delete it and this PL/SQL block will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a SQL SELECT statement within an anonymous block (in PL/SQL - between the BEGIN and the END keywords) you must select INTO something so that PL/SQL can utilize a variable to hold your result from the query. It is important to note here that if you are selecting multiple columns, (which you are by "SELECT *"), you must specify multiple variables or a record to insert the results of your query into.

for example:

```
SELECT 1 
INTO v_dummy 
FROM dual;
```

---

```
SELECT 1, 2 
INTO v_dummy, v_dummy2 
FROM dual;
```

---

It is also worth pointing out that if your `SELECT * FROM....` will return multiple rows, PL/SQL will throw an error. You should only expect to retrieve 1 row of data from a SELECT INTO.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error is from the second select query.

```
select * from demo_orders where CUSTOMER_ID = custID;
```

PL-SQL won't allow a standalone sql select query for info.

http://pls-00428.ora-code.com/

You need to do some operation with the second select query